# How to extract tables and images from website's json object?

Tags: json, json-extract, html-tableextract

```
"table-wrap": {
              "@id": "ams2322-tbl-0001",
              "@xml:lang": "en",
              "@orientation": "portrait",
              "@position": "float",
              "label": "Table 1",
              "caption": {
                "p": "Strength of recomendations"
              },
              "table": {
                "@frame": "hsides",
                "@rules": "groups",
                "col": [
                  {
                    "@style": "border-right:solid 1px #000000",
                    "@span": "1"
                  },
                  {
                    "@style": "border-right:solid 1px #000000",
                    "@span": "1"
                  },
                  {
                    "@style": "border-right:solid 1px #000000",
                    "@span": "1"
                  },
                  {
                    "@style": "border-right:solid 1px #000000",
                    "@span": "1"
                  },
                  {
                    "@style": "border-right:solid 1px #000000",
                    "@span": "1"
                  }
                ],
                "thead": {
                  "@valign": "top",
                  "tr": {
                    "@style": "border-bottom:solid 1px #000000",
                    "th": [
                      {
                        "@align": "left",
                        "@valign": "top",
                        "@rowspan": "1",
                        "@colspan": "1",
                        "#text": "Strength of Recommendation"
                      },
                      {
                        "@align": "left",
                        "@valign": "top",
                        "@rowspan": "1",
                        "@colspan": "1",
                        "#text": "Recommend (1)"
                      },
                      {
                        "@align": "left",
                        "@valign": "top",
                        "@rowspan": "1",
                        "@colspan": "1",
                        "#text": "Suggest (2)"
                      },
                      {
                        "@align": "left",
                        "@valign": "top",
                        "@rowspan": "1",
                        "@colspan": "1",
                        "#text": "Suggest against (2)"
                      },
                      {
                        "@align": "left",
                        "@valign": "top",
                        "@rowspan": "1",
                        "@colspan": "1",
                        "#text": "Recommend against (1)"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "tbody": {
                  "tr": [
                    {
                      "td": [
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "Content of recommendation"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "Strong recommendation in support of an intervention"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "(Weak) Suggestion in support of an intervention under certain conditions"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "(Weak) Suggestion against an intervention under certain conditions"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "Strong recommendation against an intervention"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "td": [
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "Wording of recommendation"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "We recommend\u2014[intervention]"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "We suggest\u2014[intervention]"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "We suggest against\u2014[intervention]"
                        },
                        {
                          "@align": "left",
                          "@rowspan": "1",
                          "@colspan": "1",
                          "#text": "\u2014We recommend against [intervention]"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "permissions": {
                "copyright-holder": "John Wiley & Sons, Ltd"
              }
            }
```

Hi, I want to extract tables from json object and format them dataframe.
For example this table wrap is one of the table of the article and I want to make it as real table for printing. But I don't know how can I do that. Do you have any idea have can I do that?

And also same thing for figures and images..

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a particular scripting or programming language in mind for this project? As it is, your question is quite vague.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Python. What  I mean is when we are doing web scraping, assume the format of fetched data is XML or JSON file. I want to find images and tables from these files and store them.